# Help understanding a 30 year old schematic for a contact aligner

Tags: transistors, transformer, diagram, contact

I got this old contact aligner I want to fix up but it is missing the control box, this is the diagram which is from like 30 years ago. Any suggestions on how to interpret this? J2 and J3 are the main cables which connect to the unit, i see the capacitors, and the BJT, doesn't seem that the rectifier or transformer is labeled? Any help is much appreciated, I am more on the device fabrication side then the EE side.

[Manual, Pg 75 starts diagram](https://intranet.mne.ksu.edu/static/webattach/files/5773d86b-Q2001_Manual.pdf)

[image]

Comment: I like the insert between pages 17 & 18 ....

Comment: Theory of operation on pages 34-51 and timing diagrams in appendix seem to tell you much of what you need to know. Looks doable if you **HAD** to do it, buy buying a surplus one from ANYWHERE looks preferable. What is the system worth? How much is the job worth?

Comment: Looks like it sold, but they has one [**here**](http://www.ebay.com/itm/262287086854) for $US1500, and [**here**](http://www.wotol.com/quintel-q2001ct-q4000-4-high-resolution-mask-align/second-hand-machinery/prod_id/278737) for $25,000!!!, Active auction Korea $1500 [**here**](http://www.ebayshopkorea.com/main/view?itemID=262287086854) - tell them "send me the controller ..." | [Russian seller, Singapore location](http://www.tebebuy.ru/ebay_find.html?category=58290&level=4&id=262287086854) $1500, :-). ||

Comment: [Skip this one !!!](http://www.ebay.com/itm/like/162077520184?item=162077520184&lgeo=1&vectorid=229466&rmvSB=true) :-).

Comment: Thanks for trying, I know I have been trying to look around. I am a college student and this is just a side project to upgrade my setup, I make basic devices at home. This isn't for any profit just personal learning so I am trying to keep it as cheap as possible. The contact aligner itself was only $400 shipped.

Answer (score 2):

The rectifier is the diamond-shaped component in the upper left with "RECT." in the center. This is a somewhat uncommon symbol for a bridge rectifier. The top and bottom corners, marked `y`, are the input, and the other two corners marked `+` and `-` are the output.

[image: Rectifier]

The transformer is just above and to the left of that:

[image: Transformer]

Each set of squiggly lines represents one separate winding of the transformer. The ones on the left side of the vertical lines (representing the core) are the primary windings, and the ones on the right are the secondaries.

Other notable visible components include:

- Two fuses, marked `F1` through `F3`. Looks like `~`. F1 is on the power input, and the other two are attached to pins on connector P3.
- One resistor, marked `R1`, across capacitor C3. (Probably used to bleed off charge when the device is powered off.)
- Two diodes, marked `D1` and `D2`, in the lower left (look like `-|<-`).
- Two relays, marked `R1` and `R2` (!), in boxes at the bottom. The markings inside the box indicate how the contacts are configured.

Comment: Yeah, though I suppose this diagram doesn't give me much to go on like what transformer or diodes I should buy and then what relays.

Comment: Correct. The schematic doesn't have any of the information you'd need to replace the transformer. The full schematic might have included a BOM with details, but that doesn't appear to be part of the service manual.

Comment: You might have to figure out what voltages and currents you need and [wind your own transformer](http://electronicdesign.com/power/build-your-own-transformer). Sounds like a pain, but it's actually not that bad. There are even modern [toroid kits](https://toroid.com/Transformer-Products/Transformer-kits) for doing so very neatly. Or, search eBay or CraigsList and hope somebody has a control box.

Comment: @rdtsc The hardware in question is a "wafer alignment system", used in semiconductor production. OP is very unlikely to find parts for sale *anywhere*, let alone on Craigslist…

Comment: @duskwuff well I did say "hope." :)

Comment: I am trying to contact the person who I got the manual from, maybe they can take a few pictures with their unit to help narrow down some of the parts. I am trying to search on ebay but it is hard to find and even when I do I am a student with a low budget. I got the contact aligner cheap and am working on it to use in my own little lab.

Comment: @Transistor Stepping back for a minute - what do you plan on using this for? It's a rather esoteric piece of equipment, and is unlikely to be much use to a student -- you'd need a very expensive laboratory setup, with a lot of other hardware, to make any use of it.

Comment: It is not as expensive as you think. I already make 70s era devices with high quality 7um transparencies, NaOH developer, modified motor with tape for a spin coater, HF to etch, spin-on doped glass for dopant, kiln for diffusion/oxidation, metalization either external company or tollens reagent. This is an upgrade for my modified probe station contact aligner I was using.

Comment: @Transistor Wow, okay, I'm pretty impressed. Good luck! :)